# What do we know about the timeline of deaths _within_ famines, from historical wartime occurrences?

Tags: war, death, famine

Pardon the ghoulish subject, I am trying to find historical examples of famines during wartime to see how they evolved.

- how many months in did people start dying?
- was the death rate constant during the whole event?  I expect not, but what does the curve look like?  Does it start slowly then accelerate?
- did deaths continue *after* food supply resumed?

I tried to look for "famine deaths timeline by month" or "curve".  All I've tended to see is macro reports about how many deaths have happened each year historically.  Or aggregate numbers at each event:  x at Leningrad, y during Great Leap Forward.

Leningrad's history is unlikely to be all that reliable, so I thought of looking up Holland's 1944-45 [Hunger Winter](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6226247/).  Wealth of info, but not much detail on the timeline.

[Wikipedia's entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_famine_of_1944%E2%80%931945), though not as extensive, has some elements of what I am looking for:

> Butter disappeared after October 1944

> Deaths in the three big cities of the Western Netherlands (The Hague, Rotterdam, and Amsterdam) started in earnest in December 1944, reaching a peak in March 1945,[10] but remained very high in April and May 1945. Malnutrition was rampant throughout all of the country. The famine was fully underway by January but the deadliest month would become March 1945.

That's a start, but rather vague.  Seems like a subject that would have received more formal historical analysis.

One of the Stalingrad books I've read (Beevor's?) went into some depth in the circumstances of the *first* death by malnutrition and gave the exact date.  Any estimates of total deaths up to the surrender date and their rate?

Alternatively, older city sieges would also work, *if they contain that type of breakdown*.

Comment: I'm surprised I'm not easily finding comparative studies. There are certainly plenty of relevant case studies. Here's a quick example which is open access: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/01615440.2017.1285260

Comment: @BrianZ *Figure 2. Deaths per 1,000 of the population, by region, sex, and year and month of death, in The Netherlands, 1944–7.* would be a good answer.  So would figure 4. 
 We know food supply collapses in October and we can see that the deaths spike way up from Dec-Jan.  Futhermore we see excess deaths - over the pre-famine, but in-war, baseline - past May 8th, when the Germans surrendered.